# How to change the color of a ListView column (each cell of each row) seperately in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, colors, model-binding

I have a ListView that regularly update and show some analyzed data.
Each row represent a different source and the columns show it's analyzed values.

What I want is to only change the Background color or Font Color of a single cell if a certain criteria is met.

For example if the "Price" Column value become less than X, it will change into Red Color background or font.
But I don't want the whole row to be changing color, but only the "Price" Column of that certain row.

I know how to change the color of a whole row, there has been many example of that in here as well, for example using binding. But I want to know if there is anyway to just change the Background Color or Font Color of a single Cell.

Thanks.

Edit:
Thanks to Sean Manton's Reply, I solved this problem pretty easily. It's surprising that I had so much problem finding any result in my searches for this, so I added my own answer with a working example as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GridViewColumn` has a `CellTemplate` property that you can point to a `DataTemplate` for the cells. In the `DataTemplate` you can use a Binding Converter to map the values to the desired styling.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Not sure how I missed this when I searched for changing the color of a column/cell for several hours, but after I checked CellTemplate property, I solved it easily and even made a reply with an example of it, maybe it help someone else next time :D

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem pretty easily after I search for the CellTemplate usage, Thanks to Sean Manton's reply.

Not sure why it was so hard for me to find this when I searched for changing color of ListView Column or Cell and the result only showed it for "Row" and not "Column".

Also, Most of the answers here always use a Binding Converter, which seems to be the better way to do it, But I noticed this can work even without any converter and with a very simple code as well.

So I will write this example here in case anyone find it useful:

XAML Design:

```
<ListView x:name="myListView">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ID}" Header="ID" />
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" Header="Name" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Price">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Price}" Foreground="{Binding Price_Color}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

As for the C# Code, We just have to make a list which include the "Price_Color" string value as well.

```
public class myListViewItem
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
    public string Price_Color { get; set; }
}
```

And now we can very easily add and customize the items with our desired color like this :

```
List<myListViewItem> myItemList = new List<myListViewItem>();
myItemList.Add(new myListViewItem { ID = 1, Name = "Book", Price = 15.7, Price_Color = "Green" });
myItemList.Add(new myListViewItem { ID = 2, Name = "Laptop", Price = 4000, Price_Color = "Red" });
myItemList.Add(new myListViewItem { ID = 2, Name = "Mobile", Price = 3000, Price_Color = "#FFF2CC" });
MyListView.ItemsSource = myItemList;
```

Now we will have 3 row in our ListView each one having a different font color for the "Price" Column only.

Comment: Yes, you can certainly do it that way instead of using binding converters. In most scenarios of a list or grid, I would assume that colors would be assigned programmatically based on category or something like that, rather than manually. You can achieve that with your solution as well by just making it an expression bodied property e.g. `Price_Color => ConvertToColor(Price);`. Binding converters is just the way if you want to keep the responsibility of styling within the view.

Comment: As far as which is the better way to do it... I think your way works fine and is much easier to follow for simple scenarios where views and viewmodels are very 1:1. But if you need to display the same data in different views with different styling choices then you'll be much better off using binding converters in xaml so each view has the flexibility to implement. So it's good to at least understand the binding converter approach. But it's also good to know your approach as it gets you there in less files and you can always refactor to BCs later so it is a good agile starting point

Comment: Yeah, Thanks for the extra details :D